# How do I use CSS to highlight links to a specific site by showing their favicon?

Tags: css, favicon

On my website, I want to highlight my affiliate links to `example.com` by showing their favicon next to links to their website automatically, or, if not pulling their specific favicon, using a book icon from FontAwesome. I would also like to style these links in a different color, and set this up in the tidiest way possible. How would I set this up in CSS?

Comment: To the close voters saying the question needs more focus, the focus is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could target them using a [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to match any links with the string `example.com` in their `href` attribute:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a[href*='example.com']:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Not an affiliated link</a>
<a href="https://example.com">Affiliated link</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/foobar">Also affiliated link</a>
```

Comment: When you delete your own "cant be done, best you can do is" because you learned something new. thanks

Answer (score 0):

How would I add in a image to this CSS code, so that the result is:

```
<a href="#">Not an affiliated link</a>
<a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://example.com/favico.co">Affiliated link</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/foobar"><img src="https://example.com/favico.co">Also affiliated link</a>
```